# Issue with TypeScript compilation in Angular2 Forms

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I have defined a form in Angular2 like that:

```
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
        password: ['',Validators.required],
        passwordRepeat: ['',Validators.required]
    });
```

where

```
public form:ControlGroup
```

Which is fine, as:

```
 _formBuilder = FormBuilder.group(controlsConfig: {
        [key: string]: any;
    }, extra?: {
        [key: string]: any;
    }): modelModule.ControlGroup
```

it returns `ControlGroup`.

Now, in my component I am using:

```
this.user.password = this.passwordEditForm.controls.password.value;
```

Which throws me compilation error of:

```
error TS2339: Property 'password' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
```

Seems like a bug. Any ideas on how I can overcome this issue? I've tried doing so:

```
export interface FormControlGroup extends ControlGroup{
password:any;
}
```

But this gives me even more errors:

```
error TS1206: Decorators are not valid here.
app/form.component.ts(30,9): error TS2322: Type 'ControlGroup' is not assignable to type 'FormControlGroup'.
  Property 'password' is missing in type 'ControlGroup'.
app/form.component.ts(37,61): error TS2339: Property 'password' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
```

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: angular 2 2.0.0-beta.8

Answer (score 9):

replace the following :

```
this.user.password = this.passwordEditForm.controls.password.value;
```

with

```
this.user.password = this.passwordEditForm.controls['password'].value;
```

It works for me. I thinks it's only a workaround.

Comment: Worked here as well, can check off answer. Thanks dude

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked fine here :)

Comment: Ok, this is a workaroud. What is the solution to these errors?