# Angular 2 AbstractControl runtime

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, runtime

I was following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064881/3874858 to implement "Add more" ability to my Angular 2 application. Project, associated with this answer is uploaded on http://plnkr.co/edit/nHSIsciSZNTQzQjxkXsk?p=preview. Unfortunately, to start this project, I have to comment these lines

```
this.form.controls.payOffs.push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(po))
this.form.controls.payOffs.push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(emptyPayOff));
console.log("Added New Pay Off", this.form.controls.payOffs)
this.form.controls.payOffs.removeAt(index);
```

and type "npm start" and then uncomment. If I do not comment them, I get these errors:

app/Components/companyInsertion.component.ts(37,28): error TS2339: Property 'payOffs' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
app/Components/companyInsertion.component.ts(56,24): error TS2339: Property 'payOffs' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
app/Components/companyInsertion.component.ts(57,57): error TS2339: Property 'payOffs' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.
app/Components/companyInsertion.component.ts(63,24): error TS2339: Property 'payOffs' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl; }'.

So, as I understand, this code works only on runtime. I tried this solution, but it didn't seemed to help:
[Issue with TypeScript compilation in Angular2 Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987494/issue-with-typescript-compilation-in-angular2-forms)
by changing

```
this.form.controls.payOffs.push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(po))
```

To

```
this.form.controls['payOffs'].value.push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(po))
```

So now I can run the app, but I extremely dislike the necessity to comment each time I start the server. Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

It sucks but the only way I've found around these Typescript errors are to cast to a `FormArray` first. It's really annoying, I'm hoping a typings update for Angular 2 in the future might help resolve.

```
(<FormArray> this.form.find('pay_offs')).push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(po))
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found is:

```
(this.form.controls as any)['payOffs'].value.push(this.createPayOffFormGroup(po))
```

Comment: This works, but it is just a workaround. What is the solution?